# Not sure how to blit font with a variable onto a surface, pygame

Tags: python, pygame

trying to blit onto the screen a font with a variable - the score you have achieved - onto the screen after dying.

```
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
font_small = pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana", 20)
scoreMsg = "Your score: {0}".format(SCORE)
show_score = font_small.render(scoreMsg, True, BLACK)
```

later on I call the show_score variable like this:

```
screen.blit(show_score, (30, 400))
```

here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/5RnShSCG

edit: i forgot to mention. the text "Your score:" shows up on the screen, but the variable is always 0, even if score is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SCORE` is not tied to the `show_score` surface. The `show_score` surface does not magically change when you change `SCORE`. You must rerender the `show_score` surface:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  # [...]

  def move(self):

    global SCORE, show_score
    
    self.rect.move_ip(0,SPEED)
    if (self.rect.top > 600):
      self.rect.top = 0
      SCORE+=1

      show_score = font_small.render("Your score: {0}".format(SCORE), True, BLACK)

      self.rect.center = (random.randint(30, 370), 0)
```